# Generate thumbnail of videos sent from frontend flask

Tags: python, opencv, flask, video, ffmpeg

I want to generate a thumbnail(say, extract frame at 1s) for videos user uploaded and sent back from the frontend.
`user_upload = request.files['file']`
What is the proper way for doing that? Is it possible to extract the frame without saving the file locally and read in first?

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', user_upload, '-ss',
                     '00:00:00.000', '-vframes', '1', output_dir])
```

or

```
     vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(user_upload)
     success, image = vidcap.read()
     count = 0
     while success and count < 1:
         cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
         success, image = vidcap.read()
         print('Read a new frame: ', success)
         count += 1
```

both `FFmpeg` and `cv2` require to read in a `Path`, not a `FileStorage`.

```
  File "/Users/glwang/bikan/yc2020/eb-flask/siyu/utils.py", line 8, in capture_thumnail
    '00:00:00.000', '-vframes', '1', output_dir])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1275, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage
```

Also, when I tried to first save the file locally and use `FFmpeg`for extracting the frame,
`user_upload.save('path/to/somewhere')`
it shows

```
File "/siyu/utils.py", line 7, in capture_thumnail
    video_input.save(video_input.filename)
  File "/Users/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 3070, in save
    copyfileobj(self.stream, dst, buffer_size)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 79, in copyfileobj
    buf = fsrc.read(length)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 738, in read
    return self._file.read(*args)
ValueError: read of closed file
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate thumbnail of videos sent from frontend flask

for that you can't use the `request.files.get('file')`  you have two way to do this

1. You can save the `request.files.get('file')` in temp file and then you use the path link to generate the thumbnail. here is example

   ```
   video = request.files['video']
   video_bytes = video.read()

   with open("filename.mp4","wb") as f:
        f.write(video_bytes)
        f.close()

   #get thumbnail from video
   cmd = f'ffmpeg -i "filename.mp4" -ss 00:00:01.000 -vframes 1  -s 640x360  "thumbnail.png"'

   subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)

   #for deleting the video file
   #os.remove("filename.mp4")
   ```
2. From the video url Url

   ```
   cmd = f'ffmpeg -i "video file url" -ss 00:00:01.000 -vframes 1  -s 640x360  "thumbnail_file_name.png"'
   print(cmd)
   subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
   ```